# IE7 Handle Combination Keypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-7

How can I handle keypresses in Javascript in IE7 that are Key Combinations?

For example, I'd like the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to fire my notification script.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using jQuery is an option, you could take a look at this project:

http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/

If jQuery is not an option but the focus is only on IE7 (only tested in that), you could use the following code example to build on:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function handleKeyDown() {
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 17) {
         alert('ctrl-i pressed!');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="handleKeyDown()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer but unfortunately no.

Comment: Edit: Added non-jquery example, hope this helps!