# Override Internet Explorer Events for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, xna

I'm creating an application that uses XNA and Silverlight. What I want to do is to be able to use shortcuts and commands that IE normally picks up. For example, if I press Control-S, I don't want IE to save the page. I want to do my own action.

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235716/disable-keyboard-enter-key

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can't do that. Because Internet Explorer has its own behavior and you can't change the way that these behaviors do.

So, you must implement another way to implement shortcuts on your Silverlight's application.