# Disable "backspace" key across app in EmberJs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way in **EmberJs** to disable the `backspace` key, so it doesn't navigate back in the browser history?

Currently using `EmberJs 2.0`

I did find this possible answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235723/1913888

But one trick to this, is that a `backspace` action should work for example in an input box, but not for navigating back in the window history.

Thank you

Comment: Check if the event target is the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my app, I just listen for the keydown and check to see if it is triggered on the body.

```
$(window).on("keydown", function(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode===8 && evt.target.nodeName==="BODY") {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Other option is to check to make sure the target is not an input/content-editable.

Comment: The code snippet looks good.  I'm just wondering, how would you test this in Qunit for example?  Also, where do you put the above snippet in your Ember App?  Thank you for your help *epascarello*